# CSS Positioning - Two Column Div Layout with Two fixed top DIVs

Tags: css, css-position

I am attempting to put together a webpage layout with the following elements:
1. A two column setup with menu on the left and main content on the right.
2. A "function bar" fixed to the top of the right column. Fixed and always visible.

Here are the catches:

1. I want the two columns to scroll independently of each other if their height pushes past the browser window resolution
2. The Content Managment System I use adds a fixed pane to the top of the page to show control options

I have crafted an image that gives a visual representation of the layout I am after. I hope it helps this make sense.

[Image of layout for reference](http://www.yandasmusic.com/Portals/1/Images/new-layout-image.png)

Here's where I'm at currently in attempting to create this layout

```
<div class="CMS-Admin-Bar"></div>
<div class="total-wrapper">
    <div class="left-pane">
        <div class="menu-pane"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-pane">
        <div class="Function-Pane"></div>
        <div class="Content-Pane"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.CMS-Admin-Bar{
position:fixed;
height:43px;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:10;
}

.total-wrapper{
position:relative;
}

.left-pane{
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:283px;
z-index:8;
}

.right-pane{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:283px;
right:0;
bottom:0;
overflow:auto;
}

.Function-Pane{
position:fixed;
z-index:8;
top:0px;
left:283px;
height:43px;
}
```

With this CSS I have a few problems:

1. The "CMS-Admin-Bar" covers my "Function-Pane" when an admin is logged in.
2. The "Function-Pane"'s right 283px is being cut off. I need this fixed div to fit in the screen, while still having a fluid width.

I hope I was descriptive enough. Thanks for your help and time!

Alex

Comment: Fix your CSS to have proper line breaks. It's always a pain to read elements with multiple declarations on the same line, then with line breaks. It will be easier to read.

Comment: I tried to clean it up a bit. Hope that helped!

Comment: +1 for a code clean up! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kEhny **UPDATED AGAIN**

**The "CMS-Admin-Bar" covers my "Function-Pane" when an admin is logged in.**
You will need to find the height of the CMS-Admin-Bar and add padding to the parent element (might be the body for this case) or add a top margin to the total-wrapper element.

**The "Function-Pane"'s right 283px is being cut off. I need this fixed div to fit in the screen, while still having a fluid width.**
It seems like it works in the pen now. Note that this layout really isn't responsive though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bill. There are a couple "must haves" for my markup, which are not currently in your example.

1. The left pane must be a fixed width, while the right pane must be responsive to fill the remainder page width.

2. The function pane must be fixed to the top of the right pane.

3. The admin bar must "push down" the "total wrapper" when it is present (which is only for admins)

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure if you can create two element side by side where one is a set pixel width AND the second is whatever is leftover for the browser. Let me see what I can do though.

Comment: So I updated the the Pen but the issue is that you can't have a fixed width and then not specify the other. I would do something with max-width or min-width in that case. Also, I strongly suggest trying a fluid layout if you want anything responsive.

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks for your time. I've gotten past the left/right column sizing issue already with my current CSS above. It uses fixed and absolute positioning on the two columns to allow for a single fixed width column. The only issues I'm having are the two numbers above labeled "a few problems".

Comment: I updated my answer based on your questions solely and updated the pen. Hope that clears it up. Good luck!